# Dealing with error message narrowing from type object to type string

Tags: vb.net, option-strict

I am getting this error message when converting code from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.5:

> Option strict on disallows narrowing from type 'object' to type
>   'string' in copying the value of 'ByRef' parameter 'ParamValue' back
>   to the matching argument.

The code looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function TheFunction(ByRef x As Object ) As Integer
    TheFunction = 5
    // ultimately called like this: SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("field", x)
End Function

Private Function AFunction(ByVal x As String) As Boolean

   Dim cnt As Integer = TheFunction(x)

End Function
```

I have googled for answers and it seems the suggestion is to change the `TheFunction`.

I am constrained in that I cannot change `TheFunction`.

I can turn off strict, but I would rather put in a good fix for this problem like copying x to a different variable and passing that variable in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
Dim boxedObject as Object = CType(x, Object)
Dim cnt As Integer = TheFunction(boxedObject)
x = CType(boxedObject, String)
```

Comment: changed it a bit

Comment: That is probably the good general case, but I don't think I need the 3rd line because I don't need the returned value because it does not return a value.

Comment: then why is it byref?  In that case, TheFunction(CType(x, Object)) would be enough

Comment: I don't know why the developer chose ByRef.  Does ByRef just pass a pointer and have better performance for large strings?

Comment: I don't know if it creates another object on the stack.. I tried to Match hash code but realized that is overridden for strings

Comment: If you can't change `The Function` to remove ByRef, and you don't need to preserve changes made to `x`, then you could simply call the function with `Dim cnt As Integer = TheFunction(CObj(x))`.

Comment: @Blackwood  That was John's original answer, but then he changed it to the more general case.  I voted you up so people notice this as a viable option.